# Executing q in shell script

Tags: shell, kdb, q-lang

I need to load a q file with a hardcoded dictionary, insert a key and assign returned value from the dictionary to an environment variable inside a shell script.

This how it would look like in q:

```
q)\l /home/.../marketconfig.q

q)show marketconfig[`US]
```

This is kind of the form I need it to be in:

```
CONFIG=\`q /home/.../marketconfig.q ; show marketconfig[\`US]\`
```

Thanks for help guys!

Answer (score 1):

test.sh:

```
#/bin/bash
CONFIG=`q test.q`
echo config is $CONFIG
```

test.q:

```
-1 "FOO";
exit 0;
```

Output:

```
$ ./test.sh
KDB+ 2.7 2011.11.09 Copyright (C) 1993-2011 Kx Systems
l64/ ...

config is FOO
```

Seems to work for me. -1 prints on standard out. 0N! works too.

Comment: -1 expects a string, so if your config isn't already a string you'll need to use the string function or -3!

Answer (score 1):

In bash, you can use a heredoc:

```
#!/bin/bash
CONFIG=$(q /home/.../marketconfig.q << 'EOF'
show marketconfig[`US]
EOF
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice way to express it as one statement without a need to alter original file or add an extra file:

```
CONFIG=\`q<<<'system "l marketconfig.q"; show marketconfig[\\`US]'`
```